# Ошибка "Exception in ASGI application" в веб-приложении на FastAPI

Tags: python, rest, fastapi

Пишу API на FastAPI. Столкнулся с проблемой: при тестировании метода read_menus (и любого другого) из документации FastAPI Swagger UI, получаю ошибку:

```
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gibad\PycharmProjects\FastApiApp\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\http\httptools_impl.py", line 426, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
  File "C:\Users\gibad\PycharmProjects\FastApiApp\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\proxy_headers.py", line 84, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\gibad\PycharmProjects\FastApiApp\venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 289, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\gibad\PycharmProjects\FastApiApp\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\applications.py", line 122, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\gibad\PycharmProjects\FastApiApp\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\gibad\PycharmProjects\FastApiApp\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "C:\Users\gibad\PycharmProjects\FastApiApp\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\gibad\PycharmProjects\FastApiApp\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "C:\Users\gibad\PycharmProjects\FastApiApp\venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\middleware\asyncexitstack.py", line 20, in __call__
    raise e
    raise ResponseValidationError(
fastapi.exceptions.ResponseValidationError
```

Причем еще пять дней назад этот метод работал 5 дней назад. И с тех пор я ничего в нем не менял. Единственное, что я сделал, так это добавил новую функцию в crud.py и новый метод в main.py, с помощью которых реализовываю PATCH-метод.

Код для моделей SQLAlchemy:

```
""" SQLAlchemy models """
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, mapped_column, backref

from database import Base

""" Таблица SQLAlchemy "Меню" """
class Menu(Base):
    __tablename__ = "menus"

    menu_id = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = mapped_column(String)
    description = mapped_column(String)

    submenu = relationship("Submenu", back_populates="menu", cascade="all, delete-orphan")   # Связываем c таблицей подменю

""" Таблица SQLAlchemy "Подменю" """
class Submenu(Base):
    __tablename__ = "submenus"

    submenu_id = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)  # pk id таблицы
    submenu_name = mapped_column(String)  # название подменю
    menu_id = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey(Menu.menu_id))  # внешний ключ к таблице "Меню"

    menu = relationship("Menu", backref=backref("submenu_1", cascade="all, delete-orphan")) # связь с таблицей меню, с каскадным удалением
    dish = relationship("Dish", back_populates="sub", cascade="all, delete-orphan")                               # связь с таблицей блюд


""" Таблица SQLAlchemy "Блюдо" """
class Dish(Base):
    __tablename__ = "dishes"

    dish_id = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    dish_name = mapped_column(String)
    submenu_id = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey(Submenu.submenu_id))

    sub = relationship("Submenu", backref=backref("dish_1", cascade="all, delete-orphan")) # связь с таблицей подменю
```

Код для моделей Pydantic (schemas.py):

```
""" Pydantic models (Schemas) """
from pydantic import BaseModel

class DishBase(BaseModel):
    dish_name: str

class DishCreate(DishBase):
    pass

class Dish(DishCreate):
    dish_id: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class SubmenuBase(BaseModel):
    submenu_name: str  # название подменю

class SubmenuCrete(SubmenuBase):
    pass

class Submenu(SubmenuCrete):
    submenu_id: int
    #menu_id: int  # внешний ключ к таблице "Меню"
    dishes: list[Dish]

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class MenuBase(BaseModel):
    title: str
    description: str | None = None

class MenuCreate(MenuBase):
    pass

class Menu(MenuCreate):
    menu_id: int
    submenus: list[Submenu]

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

Код для CRUD (crud.py):

```
""" CRUD operations (Create, Read, Update, Delete) """
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

import models, schemas       # correct: "from . import" to "import"

""" Получить подменю из списка подменю по id """
def get_submenu(db: Session, submenu_id: int):
    return db.query(models.Submenu).filter(models.Submenu.submenu_id == submenu_id).first()


""" Получить подменю по названию """
def get_submenu_name(db: Session, submenu_name: str):
    return db.query(models.Submenu).filter(models.Submenu.submenu_name == submenu_name).first()


""" Получить список подменю со смещением 0 количеством 100 """
def get_submenus(db: Session, menu_id: int, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100):
    return db.query(models.Submenu).filter(models.Submenu.menu_id == menu_id).offset(skip).limit(limit).all()


""" Создание подменю """
def create_submenu(db: Session, submenu: schemas.SubmenuCrete, menu_id):
    db_submenu = models.Submenu(**submenu.model_dump(), menu_id=menu_id)
    #db_submenu = models.Submenu(submenu_name=submenu.submenu_name)  # Создаем модель(запись) подменю
    db.add(db_submenu)                                              # Добавляем модель(запись) в базу
    db.commit()                                                     # сохраняем изменения
    db.refresh(db_submenu)                                          # обновляем запись
    return db_submenu

""" Получить конкретное меню """
def  get_menu(db: Session, menu_id: int):
    return db.query(models.Menu).filter(models.Menu.menu_id == menu_id).first()


""" Получить список меню со смещением 0 количеством 100 """
def get_menus(db: Session, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100):
    return db.query(models.Menu).offset(skip).limit(limit).all()


""" Создание меню """
def create_menu(db: Session, menu: schemas.MenuCreate):
    db_menu = models.Menu(**menu.model_dump())                     # Создаем модель(запись) меню
    db.add(db_menu)                                                # Добавляем модель(запись) в базу
    db.commit()                                                    # сохраняем изменения
    db.refresh(db_menu)                                            # обновляем запись
    return db_menu


""" Частичное обновление меню """
def patch_menu(db: Session, menu: schemas.Menu):
    my_title = menu.title                              # Новое название
    my_description = menu.description                  # Новое описание
    db.query(models.Menu).filter(models.Menu.menu_id == menu.menu_id).\
        update({"title": my_title, "description": my_description})  # Вносим изменение в таблицу
    db.commit()                                        # Сохраняем изменения
```

main.py

```
""" HTTP methods """
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, HTTPException
from sqlalchemy.orm import  Session

import models, schemas                     # correct: "from . import" to "import"
import crud
from database import SessionLocal, engine

#import uvicorn

models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)   # Create the database tables

app = FastAPI()  # Инициализация приложения

# Dependency (create new session)
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()


@app.get("/")
async def read_root():             # Обработка пустого get-запроса
    return {"Hello": "World"}      # выдача json-ответа {"Hello": "World"}


""" Read menu list """
@app.get("/api/v1/menus/", response_model=list[schemas.Menu], status_code=200)       # Обработка get-запроса с индексом
async def read_menus(skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):

    menus = crud.get_menus(db, skip=skip, limit=limit)  # get menu list

    if not menus:
        return []    # выдача пустого списка меню
    return menus     # Выдача непустого списка меню


""" Create a new menu """
@app.post("/api/v1/menus", response_model=schemas.Menu, status_code=201)
async def create_menu(menu: schemas.MenuCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return crud.create_menu(db=db, menu=menu)


""" Issuance concrete menu """
@app.get("/api/v1/menus/{menu_id}", response_model=schemas.Menu, status_code=200)       # Обработка get-запроса с индексом
async def read_menu(menu_id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):

    db_menu = crud.get_menu(db, menu_id)
    if db_menu is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Menu is not found")
    return db_menu

"""
@app.patch("/api/v1/menus/{menu_id}", response_model=schemas.Menu, status_code=200)
async def patch_menu(menu: schemas.Menu, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return crud.patch_menu(db, menu)
"""

"""
@app.delete("/api/v1/menus/{menu_id}", status_code=200)
async def delete_menu(menu_id: int):
    id_list = list(myMenu.keys())

    if menu_id in id_list:
        myMenu.pop(menu_id)
"""


""" Get all submenus in menu with concrete menu_id """
@app.get("/api/v1/menus/{menu_id}/submenus", response_model=list[schemas.Submenu], status_code=200)       # Обработка get-запроса с индексом
async def read_submenus(menu_id: int, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    submenus = crud.get_submenus(db, menu_id=menu_id, skip=skip, limit=limit)
    return submenus


""" Create a new submenu """
@app.post("/api/v1/menus/{menu_id}/submenu", response_model=schemas.Submenu, status_code=201)
async def create_submenu(menu_id: int, submenu: schemas.SubmenuCrete, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return crud.create_submenu(db, submenu=submenu, menu_id=menu_id)


""" Get the submenu with submenu_id from the menu with menu_id"""
@app.get("/api/v1/menus/{menu_id}/submenus/{submenu_id}", response_model=schemas.Submenu, status_code=200)       # Обработка get-запроса с индексом
async def read_submenu(submenu_id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    db_menu = crud.get_menu(db, submenu_id)
    if db_menu is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Menu is not found")
    return db_menu



@app.patch("/api/v1/menus/{menu_id}/submenus/{submenu_id}", status_code=200)
async def patch_menu(menu: schemas.Menu, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return crud.patch_menu(db, menu)
```

Я искал на просторах интернета, но так и не нашел никакой полезной инфорамации. И в докуменатации я не нашел информации, что означает эта ошибка. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Не правильно настроена `response_model`.

Вы уверены что ваши эндпоинты точно возвращают экземпляры класса `schemas.Submenu`?

Например я начал смотреть первый попавшийся эндпоинт и заметил, что функция `get_submenus` возвращает не экземпляр класса `schemas.Submenu`

```
""" Get all submenus in menu with concrete menu_id """
@app.get("/api/v1/menus/{menu_id}/submenus", response_model=list[schemas.Submenu], status_code=200)       # Обработка get-запроса с индексом
async def read_submenus(menu_id: int, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    submenus = crud.get_submenus(db, menu_id=menu_id, skip=skip, limit=limit)
    return submenus
```

Либо не указывайте ничего в `response_model`, либо будьте уверены что будете возвращать именно то что указали в данном аттрибуте.

Как решение предлагаю

1. Убрать `response_model` и возвращать все через `JSONResponse()`.
2. Ну или если вам обязательно указывать `response_model=list[schemas.Submenu]`, то возвращайте список элементов `schemas.Submenu`. А этого можно добиться так в нужной функции в файле `crud.py` пропишите например:

```
# здесь все ваши операции по получению нужных вам даннных из бд
# допустим все данные находятся в переменной res
return schemas.Submenu(
    id=res.id,
    name=res.name,
    count=res.count
)
```

Схема абстрактная, но ее будет не сложно настроить под ваши нужды, и еще прошу заметить что если обьекты схем вложены друг в друга, как это происходит у вас в `schemas.Submenu`, нужно будет вложенные обьекты так же превратить в схемы. Если этот вариант покажется вам сложным или не нужным, то можно воспользоваться первым решением которое я предложил выше.

Подробнее можете почитать [здесь](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/)